# How to get the top 5 username's with highest values using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[image: query]  I wish to get the top 5 users without repeating the usernames using SQL Server.
I have the following code to count the id's that I use in another website.

```
SELECT follow_id,count(id) AS cnt FROM table 
GROUP BY follow_id ORDER BY cnt DESC  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: write order by count(id) desc to achieve this.

Comment: in your example, which results do you want?

Comment: Hey @fthiella i want {test4,bruno,michael,jc, "another"}
note: "another" is one other user with highest value, i forgot to put one more in the example image

Comment: Your screenshot has a .mdf filename - are you really wanting SQL suitable for MySQL, or would SQL Server be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   top 5 username
FROM     yourtable
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: hey @fthiella i dont think limit is supported, this is the error i get [error][1] [1]:https://u0svcw.bn1302.livefilestore.com/y2pJ9tnIAkgLRcXbHz6vSkSwkb8dBC-z5436o_HVBea3tCSCELw5n-Y-dNHotvf8U93b9Qz7FIf8r9E6vRpx2pbswwmpdRn-pq60HJfARrYt-E/Capture2.JPG

Comment: Is your database MySQL or SQL Server?  MySQL definitely supports `limit`.  SQL Server uses `top` in the `select` statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry i edited the post to SQL Server.

Comment: @fthiella . . . Hope you don't mind.  I changed your answer to be for SQL Server rather than MySQL, because the question changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DISTINCT to help you eliminate duplicates

SELECT distinct username 
FROM table 
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 5;

Another alternative is to use GROUP BY clause, it has the effect of removing duplicates and selecting only the unique combinations of values in the specified columns:

SELECT  count(id), username
FROM table
GROUP BY username
limit 5